# Understanding remote JMS connections within JBoss EAP 6.4 (HornetQ)

Tags: java, jms, hornetq, jboss-eap-6

We have some issues with too many TCP connections in our environment so we are trying to limit as many connections as possible. Therefore, I've set the activation configuration property `maxSession` to `1` to all our remote MDBs:

```java
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "user", propertyValue = "jmsuser"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "password", propertyValue = "xxxx"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "minSession", propertyValue = "1"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "1"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "myQueue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionParameters", propertyValue = "host=127.0.0.1;port=5545"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectorClassName", propertyValue = "org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory") }, 
mappedName = "myQueue")
public class ReadQueueTest implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        //do something...   
    }
}
```

After starting the application within one MDB I get the following TCP connections:

```
######:~ user$ netstat -an | grep 5545 | grep ESTA
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.5545         127.0.0.1.64644        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.64644        127.0.0.1.5545         ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.5545         127.0.0.1.64643        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.64643        127.0.0.1.5545         ESTABLISHED
```

After a few minutes the connection count is increasing:

```
######:~ user$ netstat -an | grep 5545 | grep ESTA
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.5545         127.0.0.1.64652        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.64652        127.0.0.1.5545         ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.5545         127.0.0.1.64644        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.64644        127.0.0.1.5545         ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.5545         127.0.0.1.64643        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.64643        127.0.0.1.5545         ESTABLISHED
```

Can somebody tell me why there are so many connections, and why is it increasing? Is it possible to limit the TCP connections to one for each remote MDB?

We are using JBoss EAP 6.4 with HornetQ.